# Files loading to AppEngine with space characters in name not found

Tags: php, google-app-engine, drupal

I have created a Google AppEngine and loaded the Drupal extension     http://blog.boombatower.com/drupal-integration-module-google-app-engine

This loaded and ran correctly.

I then added the rest of an existing Drupal site, and added some extra entries in the settings.php file to handle additional facilities, including memcache and FB

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
// The 'cache_form' bin must be assigned no non-volatile storage.
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'something_unique';

require_once "sites/all/libraries/purl-master/src/Purl.php";

include "sites/all/modules/fb/fb_url_rewrite.inc";
include "sites/all/modules/fb/fb_settings.inc";
```

When I load the site to the AppEngine and then view I get errors regarding files not found. These are image files which have a space character in the name. The referencing URL looks correct. Other image files without a space in the name work correctly.

```
17:32:41.844 Static file referenced by handler not found: __static__/sites/default/files/images/frontpage/Titan%20@%20Kiva%20Beach.jpg
```

I will move this and my other files to Cloud storage after I have the basics running.

When I check for instances of the AppEngine none are showing. Yet the site loads and runs / partially, I have issues with responsive menus which is preventing me access the admin and other pages

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in responsive_menus_glob_recursive() (line 491 of /base/data/home/apps/s~app-laketahoe-com/1.374191105859253183/sites/all/modules/responsive_menus/responsive_menus.module).
```

Not sure if this is related.

I wanted to SSH into the AppEngine to look at the file system but can't find it listed in the instances. I had added the Compute Engine at a later date but it should be independant of the App Engine.

```
greg@ubuntu:~$ gcutil listinstances

+------------------+---------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| name             | zone          | status  | network-ip   | external-ip   |
+------------------+---------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| vm-laketahoe-com | us-central1-b | RUNNING | 10.240.36.10 | 23.251.150.90 |
+------------------+---------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe filenames with spaces in them are supported at all.

Also there is a [bug with glob()](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10623) calls not working which might be the Warning you're seeing.

Lastly you cannot SSH into app engine. The admin console for your app engine apps is at https://appengine.google.com/

Comment: Stuart - Thanks for the heads up. I can work around the spaces in filenames the the bug in glob is a serious issue for us.

Comment: Sadly there is no immediate ETA on fixing glob(). Perhaps you can used opendir()/readdir()? http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/